# ¿Como poner mi sitio web visible con una ip publica?

Tags: linux, apache, servidor, ip

Me gustaria saber cual es la forma de que yo pueda acceder desde cualquier computadora a mi sitio web que estaria dentro de mi laptop convertida en servidor temporal, quisiera hacer esto por medio de la ip publica y unica que tengo por el momento, actualmente mi sitio web es visible en todos los dispositivos conectos a mi red, pero no se como hacer o que se debe de hacer para hacer que esto se lance a todos los dispositivos fuera de mi red.

Tengo un `Modem Hwaei HG8245H`

Ya aplique el `Port Mapping Configuration` del Menu `Forward Rules` y eso me permitio comunicarme dentro de mi propia red, lo que no comprendo es hacer que sea visible en todo internet. Estoy usando el sistema operativo de linux y como servidor apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te paso un video donde explican como configurar tu modem para abrir puerto.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRcLz4SUBgo

Configura un puerto de tu modem para que redireccione a tu pc en el puerto que ocupes, por defecto en los servidores web se una el puerto 80.

```
Itenernal host: ip de tu pc

External por number: 80 - 80 

Internal port number: 80 - 80
```

Un dato importante es que `no puedes acceder a tu ip publica desde tu lan directamente` por lo que te recomiendo que si quieres probar si configuraste bien tu modem, descargues [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/), ese navegador como se conecta a través de proxies puede acceder a tu ip publica desde tu lan, ademas de que se configura casi completamente en automatico.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas dirigir un dominio hacia tu ip pública. Esto lo puedes hacer gratuitamente con esta página. https://www.noip.com/

¿Porque un dominio? Porque si apagas y prendes el modem tu ip cambiará, entonces tendrás que consultarla de nuevo cada vez y si quieres montar un servidor no querrás tener que estar mandando la ip cada vez. También puedes comprarlo y dirigirlo, el problema es que tu ip cambia y tendrías que estar llamando a servicio técnico para direccionar.

Para saber si ya tienes abierto tu modem puedes buscar tu ip publica aqui: http://www.vermiip.es/ . Solo tienes que ponerla en el navegador y si todo está bien en el modem te abrirá la página de tu servidor. En realidad ahora no es muy complicado. Hay muchos tutos que también te pueden ayudar.

Hay un pequeño cliente para linux que debes descargar (Te lo proporcionan en la misma página de NO-IP) Hay que descargarlo con wget (Pa rápido).

http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/

Haces tu cuenta y creas un dominio gratis (Tiene varios a escoger). Después inicias seción con tu cuenta en el cliente de linux a través de la terminal. Esto permitirá que el servicio de no-ip se configure con tu ip publica. Es un poco latoso por que se tiene que estar actualizando cada treinta días pero en general funciona para pruebas o proyectos pequeños.

Este es un pequeño tutorial que puede servirte para la instalación: https://lignux.com/tutorial-para-instalar-no-ip-en-gnulinux/