# ¿Como redireccion a mi sitio web a travez de mis puertos habilitados?

Tags: linux, servidor, ip

Actualmente tengo un pequeño sitio web que quiero mostrar a unas ciertas personas para que lo puedan ver, pero no quiero subirlo a un servidor gratuito porque me limita mucho la funcionalidad, asi que quiero que lo vean desde mi ip public, en teoria ya active los puertos o mejor dichos abri los puertos necesarios que en este caso seria el puerto :80.

Cuando ingreso mi ip publica me sale la siguiente informacion[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La direccion de ip publica es: `https://177.229.x.x:80/`, pero dicha ip publica me muestra la ventana para iniciar la configuracion de mi router y no me muestra el sitio web que yo quisiera que se visualizara, ¿Como hago esa redireccion a mi sitio web?.

Tambien lo intente abrir en un navegador que pasara por diferentes proxys para ver si ahi me salia un resultado diferente pero por medio de tor me salio lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando el SO de Linux-Mint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[¿Como poner mi sitio web visible con una ip publica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88464/como-poner-mi-sitio-web-visible-con-una-ip-publica/88474#88474)

Te paso un video donde explican como configurar tu modem para abrir puertos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRcLz4SUBgo

Configura un puerto de tu modem para que redireccione a tu pc en el puerto que ocupes, por defecto en los servidores web se usa el puerto 80.

```
Itenernal host: ip de tu pc

External por number: 80 - 80 

Internal port number: 80 - 80
```

Un dato importante es que `no puedes acceder a tu ip publica desde tu lan directamente` por lo que te recomiendo que si quieres probar si configuraste bien tu modem, descargues Tor, ese navegador como se conecta a través de proxies puede acceder a tu ip publica desde tu lan, ademas de que se configura casi completamente en automatico.