# ¿Cómo sacar la IP pública en nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ip

He estado buscando por google un módulo o forma de sacar la IP pública en nodejs y no encuentro. Encontré un módulo llamado ip que te manda la dirección privada el router, en mi caso 192.168.56.1 pero yo quiero que salga la pública que sería esta: 76.108.84.167 en realidad quiero la IP del cliente.

Comment: Ya abriste tus puertos? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88464/como-poner-mi-sitio-web-visible-con-una-ip-publica

Comment: Tengo abierto el puerto 80 por donde corre la aplicacion en nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa externalip este te retorna tu ip publica.

https://github.com/alsotang/externalip

```
externalip(function (err, ip) {
  console.log(ip); // => 8.8.8.8
});
```

Saludos

Comment: ¿Eso da la IP del cliente?

Comment: como verás en el código le pregunta tu ip a http://ip.cn/

Comment: Gracias Rulslan López Carro. Se ve bueno ese. ¿Hay alguna alternativa por si ip.cn cae?